# Confused on Event Object Passed To Function

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events

```
   function jackpotKey(event)
   {
     var value = this.value;
     var key = event.keyCode;

     if (value.match(/^\d{3}$/) !== null && key !== 8)
     {
       this.value = value + ',';
     }
     else if((value.match(/^\d{3},\d{3}$/)) !== null && key!== 8)
     {
       this.value = value + ',';
     } 
    }
```

I am confused about how to use `this.value` and `event.keyCode` to access the property of an object that was passed to the function.

Isn't `this.value` and `event.keyCode` of the same object? If so, why wouldn't `event.value` and `this.keyCode` work?

Answer (score 1):

the event object and `this` are two different objects. `this` will reference the DOMElement that triggered the event, the event object *is* the event. Suppose we have

```
<input type="text" id="foo" value="bar"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('foo').onkeyup = function(e)//event
    {
        console.log(e === this);//false
        console.log((e.target || e.srcElement) === this);//true
        console.log(e.value);//undefined
        console.log(this.keyCode);//undefined
        console.log(e);//;logs instance of KeyboardEvent
        console.log(this);//logs input node
    };
</script>
```

Just [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPREr/) and take a look at your console

Answer (score 0):

No this and event are not same object
For example is textbox is object and event some one do key press than

-Textbox is refer to this
And
-The action of pressing is refer to event

so:

-Parameter related to textfield like it's text will be available in this object
And
-Parameter related to action like which key pressed is available event object

=>For a close look on this and event read following. and if you are new to this than you must read.

[About This](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

[About Event](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)